# CSS: resolution problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

my site has three div elements, header, content and footer. i have a picture in header, and i want, that under big resolutions too it looks nice. so i take big image, with 1800px width. by so it looks nice in resolution of 1800, but now, in small resolutions(for example 1024), it shows only first 1024px of my picture, but i want it to show the **center** 1024px of picture.
so is there any way, to set the backgound-image very big, but in small resolutions show **center** part of image?

```
#header
{
    background-image:url(../img/bg_header1.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:357px;
    width:100%;
}
```

maybe i have to chek the resolution by javascript, and then use such picture?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/background-position/

```
#header { background-position: center center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fixed height.

Comment: @durilai my problem is width, why remove the heigth? my image has the heigth of 357, and div hasn't any content, so i have to set the heigth

Comment: the height forces a image to maintain an aspect ratio.